# evernote nodejs sdk creating note with image

Tags: javascript, node.js, evernote

I am trying to create a note in evernote with an image resource, however the resource only appears as thumbnail in the left as sumbnail but not in the note itself.

Here is what I have tried.

Starting with the demo from evernote sdk https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-js I modified the express sample to create a new note.

Here is the method to create a resource from an image:

```
const crypto = require('node:crypto');
const Evernote = require('evernote');
const fs = require('fs');

function createResource(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.readFile(filename, (err, image) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        var md5 = crypto.createHash('md5');
        var hex = md5.update(image).digest('hex');

        var data = new Evernote.Types.Data();
        data.bodyHash = hex;
        data.body = image;

        var resource = new Evernote.Types.Resource();
        resource.mime = 'image/jpeg';
        resource.data = data;
        resource.attributes = new Evernote.Types.ResourceAttributes();
        resource.attributes.fileName = filename;
        resource.width = 320;
        resource.height = 200;
        resolve(resource);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Which I then use is the following method to create the note:

```
function makeNote(noteStore, noteTitle, noteBody, parentNotebook, resources) {
  var nBody = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
  nBody += '<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">';
  nBody += '<en-note>' + noteBody + '</en-note>';

  // Create note object
  var ourNote = new Evernote.Types.Note();
  ourNote.title = noteTitle;
  ourNote.content = nBody;

  if (resources && resources.length > 0) {
    // Add Resource objects to note body
    nBody += '<br /><br />';
    ourNote.resources = resources;
    for (var i in resources) {
      nBody += 'Attachment with hash: <br /><en-media type="' + resources[i].mime + '" hash="' + resources[i].data.bodyHash + '" width="200" height="200" /><br />';
    }
  }

  // parentNotebook is optional; if omitted, default notebook is used
  if (parentNotebook && parentNotebook.guid) {
    ourNote.notebookGuid = parentNotebook.guid;
  }

  // Attempt to create note in Evernote account (returns a Promise)
  noteStore.createNote(ourNote)
    .then(function(note) {
      // Do something with `note`
      console.log(note);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      // Something was wrong with the note data
      // See EDAMErrorCode enumeration for error code explanation
      // http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/reference/Errors.html#Enum_EDAMErrorCode
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

I tried to see this link in the evernote doc here (create node with attachment section)

https://dev.evernote.com/doc/articles/creating_notes.php

but unfortunately the doc is wrong and the code does not refer to the creating a resource section as it mentions.

The result is I see the new note and the image in the thumbnail but not in the note itself

[image]